# Find common keys from multiple files and store the different values into an array and calculate the differences

Tags: perl, hash

I'm very new to Perl and there's a task that I want to accomplish by perl:

I have many files look like this: (space deliminated, each has 6 columns and thousands of lines; all files ended with *.hgt)

example.hgt

```
ID     NAMES           Test1       Test2       Percentage       Height
1      abc100123        A            B          0.21            165
1      abc400123        A            B          0.99            162
1      abc300123        C            B          0.107           165
1      abc200123        A            E          0.31            167
1      abc500123        A            B          0.7             165
....
```

Each NAMES is unique in each .hgt file. I want to find the NAMES that are common in all of my .hgt files and extract all the Percentage and find the largest differences between the highest and lowest number.

For example, if I have 5 .hgt files and all of them contain NAMES = abc300123, and the according Percentage are: 0.107, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8, then the largest difference for abc300123 should be 0.9 - 0.1 = 0.8

Then I want to output the NAMES and largest difference associated with that NAMES calculated from all my files. The order of the output is sorted by the largest difference. There is an integer number ahead of each line (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). An example looks like this:

output

```
0. abc500123 0.1
1. abc900123 0.3
2. abc100123 0.7
3. abc300123 0.8
4. abc110123 0.9
....
```

I've tried to read through each files and stored the keys = NAMES and values = Percentage into arrays. I want to sort the Percentage array and store the largest and smallest values into new arrays and do the minus calculation. To some point I got stuck and couldn't put things together.

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
open(PIPEFROM, "ls *.hgt |") or die "no \.hgt files founded\!\n";  ## find the files that are ended with hgt
$i=0;
@filenames = "";

while($temp = <PIPEFROM>){

    $temp =~ m/\.hgt/;
    print out "$temp";
    $pre = $`; #gives file name without the dot and the hgt extension
    $filenames[$i] = $pre;
    $i++;
} 


%hash = ();
$j=0;
## read in files ended with .hgt
for ($i = 0; $i<=$filenames; $i++) {
$temp = $filenames[$i];

open(PIPETO, "cat $temp.hgt |") or die "no \.hgt files founded\!\n";

<PIPETO>;
while ($temp2 = <PIPETO> ){
    chomp $temp2;
    $temp2 = ~ s/^\s+//;
    @lst = split(/\s+/, $temp2);
    $NAMES = $lst[1];
    $Percentage = $lst[4];
    $hash{$NAMES} .= $Percentage . " ";
}
}
### manipulate the values
foreach $key (sort keys %hash){

    @values = split(/\s+/, $hash{$key});
    if ($#values == $#filenames){
    print "$j" . "\." . " " . "$key" . "\n";
    $j++;
                         ### got stuck
}
}
```

I'm thinking of include this into the problem, but I don't know where to put it:

```
my ($smallest, $largest) = (sort {$a <=> $b} @array)[0,-1];
```

This is so frustrating. Any kind help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You say there are thousands of unique lines in each file, yet the possible differences can only be 1 of ten values, (0.0 - 0.9), in your sample. If that is the case, you would possibly have hundreds of lines for each percentage difference. Doesn't make sense to me.  :-)

Comment: Each line is distinguished by "NAMES" and the possible differences can be anything between 0 and 1, such as 0.1, 0.25, 0.981 etc, depends on the largest and smallest value in column 5. This makes less lines for each percentage difference. And percentage difference is sorted first and NAMES is sorted the next.

Comment: Your example showed the output sorted from smallest percent to largest, i.e., ascending order. If that isn't what you want, then change the $a and $b to $b and $a within the sort command.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Joseph Myers's reply, I made a few changes to answer your question about how to get only data that occurred in all of the files, how to skip the header line, (line #1 in the input files), and sorting the output by largest percentage to smallest and sorting by name when percents are equal. Your command line entry to run the program would be like:

`perl output.pl *.hgt`.

`my $file_count = @ARGV or die "invoke program as:\nperl $0 *.hgt\n";`

This reads in in all the *.hgt to the @ARGV array, (rather than piping them in via cat as his program does). `$file_count` will then record the number of files read in. The while loop reads the files contained in `@ARGV`, similiar to piping cat.

In the first `for` loop, a check is made to see if the name was read in  in every file, (`if ($names{$name}{count} == $file_count)`). If so, it computes the difference between the percentages and if not, deletes the name from the `%names` hash.

The last `for` loop prints the results using the custom sort, `by_percent_name`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_count = @ARGV or die "invoke program as:\nperl $0 *.hgt\n";

my %names;
while (<>) {
    next if $. == 1; # throw header out
    my ($name, $perc) = (split ' ')[1,4];
    $names{$name}{count}++;
    my $t = $names{$name}{minmax} ||= [1,0];
    $t->[0] = $perc if $perc < $t->[0];
    $t->[1] = $perc if $perc > $t->[1];
    close ARGV if eof; # reset line counter, '$.',  to 1 for next file
}

for my $name (keys %names) {
    if ($names{$name}{count} == $file_count) {
        $names{$name} = $names{$name}{minmax}[1] - $names{$name}{minmax}[0];
    }
    else {
        delete $names{$name};   
    }
}

my $i;
my $total = keys %names;
for my $name (sort by_percent_name keys %names) {
    printf "%*d. %s %.6f\n", length($total), ++$i, $name, $names{$name};
}

sub by_percent_name {
    $names{$b} <=> $names{$a}   || $a cmp $b
}
```

Comment: Great contribution of the name comparison in case the percents are the same. You don't need to throw the header out. My program already took care of all that. Also, matching non-whitespace instead of splitting at a single space character is more robust, because we can't trust the exact format of the data files. For example, the data file he gave in the example was not space-separated.) In fact, you can copy and paste the entire original question into my program and it just extracts the lines of data. Thanks, however.

Comment: @Joseph Myers I saw how you handled the headers - -guess I just was using another way, not that I thought it was better. I just was adding some different ways.

Comment: It's all good, thanks! In retrospect, I wish I would have used the @ARGV like you did because then I wouldn't need to do ls *.hgt again. So saving a line of code went to wasting one. I didn't realize the OP wanted only the data that occurred in all files. Actually, that still doesn't make sense to me, because to me a lab would be taking measurements over time, and probably none of the variables would be in all the files. What would make sense is if they wanted only data with at least two/three/N measurements, for example. But this is a kind of perl program that I enjoy, so it's all good!

Answer (score 1):

This program does exactly what you specified:

```
# output.pl
# save this entire script as output.pl
# obtain output by running this command:
#
#   cat *.hgt | perl output.pl | more
# (in order to scroll the results--press "q" in order to quit)
#
#   cat *.hgt | perl output.pl > results-largest-differences-output-$$.txt
# in order to create a temporary results file
#
# BE CAREFUL because the second command overwrites whatever is in
# the output file using the ">" operator!
my %names;
my $maxcount = `ls *.hgt | wc -l`;
my %counts;
while (<>) {
my @fields = (m/(\S+)/g);
my $name = $fields[1];
my $perc = $fields[4];
next if $perc =~ m/[^.\d]/;
next unless $perc;
my $t = ($names{$name} ||= [1, 0]);
# initialize min to as high as possible and max to as low as possible
$t->[0] = $perc if $perc < $t->[0];
$t->[1] = $perc if $perc > $t->[1];
$counts{$name}++; # n.b. undef is auto-initialized to 0 before ++
}

for (keys %names) {
$names{$_} = $names{$_}->[1] - $names{$_}->[0];
}

my $n = 0;
for (sort { $names{$a} <=> $names{$b} || $a cmp $b } keys %names) {
next unless $counts{$_} == $maxcount;
$n++;
printf("%6s %20s %.2f\n", $n, $_, $names{$_});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this seems to print the NAMES and the largest percentage difference that are found in all of my test hgt files. Is there a way that I can only print those ones that have been found in every single file?

Comment: Sure, just add another hash like my %counts; and a max count like my $maxcount = 0;. In the main loop add a line that keeps track of the count for each $name. Anytime there is a count bigger than the existing maxcount, then set maxcount equal to that. Then in your final output put an if statement in front of the printf that only runs if the count for that name is equal to the maxcount.

Comment: Since you clarified what you wanted, I added a couple lines to the code. I'm writing this for you to encourage you to learn perl, one of the most efficient ways of doing a million little jobs like this.